# Get this slider to autoplay

Tags: javascript, slider

I have no clue when it comes to javascript but a client asked me if I could get this slider to autoplay. If anyone could help it would be awesome. I have tried to get it to work but to no avail so I decided to ask for help here.

https://codepen.io/mrspok407/pen/bwLwvL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const $cont = $('.cont');
    const $slider = $('.slider');
    const $nav = $('.nav');
    const winW = $(window).width();
    const animSpd = 750; // Change also in CSS
    const distOfLetGo = winW * 0.2;
    let curSlide = 1;
    let animation = false;
    let autoScrollVar = true;
    let diff = 0;
    
    // Generating slides
    let arrCities = ['Amsterdam', 'Rome', 'New—York', 'Singapore', 'Prague']; // Change number of slides in CSS also
    let numOfCities = arrCities.length;
    let arrCitiesDivided = [];

    arrCities.map((city) => {
        let length = city.length;
        let letters = Math.floor(length / 4);
        let exp = new RegExp(".{1," + letters + "}", "g");
        
        arrCitiesDivided.push(city.match(exp));
    });
    
    let generateSlide = function(city) {
        let frag1 = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
        let frag2 = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
        const numSlide = arrCities.indexOf(arrCities[city]) + 1;
        const firstLetter = arrCitiesDivided[city][0].charAt(0);

        const $slide =
                    $(`<div data-target="${numSlide}" class="slide slide--${numSlide}">
                            <div class="slide__darkbg slide--${numSlide}__darkbg"></div>
                            <div class="slide__text-wrapper slide--${numSlide}__text-wrapper"></div>
                        </div>`);

        const letter = 
                    $(`<div class="slide__letter slide--${numSlide}__letter">
                            ${firstLetter}
                        </div>`);

        for (let i = 0, length = arrCitiesDivided[city].length; i < length; i++) {
            const text = 
                        $(`<div class="slide__text slide__text--${i + 1}">
                                ${arrCitiesDivided[city][i]}
                            </div>`);
            frag1.append(text);
        }

        const navSlide = $(`<li data-target="${numSlide}" class="nav__slide nav__slide--${numSlide}"></li>`);
        frag2.append(navSlide);
        $nav.append(frag2);

        $slide.find(`.slide--${numSlide}__text-wrapper`).append(letter).append(frag1);
        $slider.append($slide);

        if (arrCities[city].length <= 4) {
            $('.slide--'+ numSlide).find('.slide__text').css("font-size", "12vw");
        }
    };

    for (let i = 0, length = numOfCities; i < length; i++) {
        generateSlide(i);
    }

    $('.nav__slide--1').addClass('nav-active');

    // Navigation
    function bullets(dir) {
        $('.nav__slide--' + curSlide).removeClass('nav-active');
        $('.nav__slide--' + dir).addClass('nav-active');
    }
    
    function timeout() {
        animation = false;
    }
    
    function pagination(direction) {
        animation = true;
        diff = 0;
        $slider.addClass('animation');
        $slider.css({
            'transform': 'translate3d(-' + ((curSlide - direction) * 100) + '%, 0, 0)'
        });
        
        $slider.find('.slide__darkbg').css({
                'transform': 'translate3d(' + ((curSlide - direction) * 50) + '%, 0, 0)'
        });
        
        $slider.find('.slide__letter').css({
                'transform': 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)',
        });
        
        $slider.find('.slide__text').css({
            'transform': 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
        });
    }
    
    function navigateRight() {
        if (!autoScrollVar) return;
        if (curSlide >= numOfCities) return;
        pagination(0);
        setTimeout(timeout, animSpd);
        bullets(curSlide + 1);
        curSlide++;
    }
    
    function navigateLeft() {
        if (curSlide <= 1) return;
        pagination(2);
        setTimeout(timeout, animSpd);
        bullets(curSlide - 1);
        curSlide--;
    }

    function toDefault() {
        pagination(1);
        setTimeout(timeout, animSpd);
    }
    
    // Events
    $(document).on('mousedown touchstart', '.slide', function(e) {
        if (animation) return;
        let target = +$(this).attr('data-target');
        let startX = e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        $slider.removeClass('animation');
        
        $(document).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
            let x = e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
            diff = startX - x;
            if (target === 1 && diff < 0 || target === numOfCities && diff > 0) return;
            
            $slider.css({
                'transform': 'translate3d(-' + ((curSlide - 1) * 100 + (diff / 30)) + '%, 0, 0)'
            });
            
            $slider.find('.slide__darkbg').css({
                'transform': 'translate3d(' + ((curSlide - 1) * 50 + (diff / 60)) + '%, 0, 0)'
            });
            
            $slider.find('.slide__letter').css({
                'transform': 'translate3d(' +  (diff / 60) + 'vw, 0, 0)',
            });
            
            $slider.find('.slide__text').css({
                'transform': 'translate3d(' + (diff / 15) + 'px, 0, 0)'
            });
        })  
    })
    
    $(document).on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
        $(document).off('mousemove touchmove');
        
        if (animation) return;
        
        if (diff >= distOfLetGo) {
            navigateRight();
        } else if (diff <= -distOfLetGo) {
            navigateLeft();
        } else {
            toDefault();
        }
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.nav__slide:not(.nav-active)', function() {
        let target = +$(this).attr('data-target');
        bullets(target);
        curSlide = target;
        pagination(1);
    }); 
    
    $(document).on('click', '.side-nav', function() {
        let target = $(this).attr('data-target');
        
        if (target === 'right') navigateRight();
        if (target === 'left') navigateLeft();
    });
    
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 39) navigateRight();
        if (e.which === 37) navigateLeft();
    });
    
    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
        if (animation) return;
    let delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        
    if (delta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) navigateLeft();
        if (delta < 0 || e.originalEvent.detail > 0) navigateRight();
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't know a thing about java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `setInterval`, this will run a function after X ms.

This function:

```js
// true or false based on existance of the attribute
const shouldAutoplay = $slider.attr('data-autoplay');
const interval = 5000; // 5 Seconds
let autoplayIntervalHandle = null;


function autoplay(shouldAutoplay, intervalInMS) {
    if (!shouldAutoplay) return;        
    autoplayIntervalHandle = setInterval(() => setTimeout(navigateRight, animSpd), intervalInMS || 3000);
}

// place this near the bottom of your $(document).ready(function() { ... });
autoplay(shouldAutoplay, interval);
```

That should be enough to get your client happy, but using a `setInterval` can make some websites slower.

I made the `autoplayIntervalHandle` so that you can reset and clear the the timer using `clearInterval`. I would only worry about it if performance issues come up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some digging I found the solution and it's actually quite simple.

Simply add

```
 setInterval(function () {
    navigateRight();
}, 3000);
```

after

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

It will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  setInterval(function () {
    navigateRight();
}, 3000);
  
  const $cont = $('.cont');
  const $slider = $('.slider');
  const $nav = $('.nav');
  const winW = $(window).width();
  const animSpd = 750; // Change also in CSS
  const distOfLetGo = winW * 0.2;
  let curSlide = 1;
  let animation = false;
  let autoScrollVar = true;
  let diff = 0;
```

I will leave this post up for anyone looking for a similar solution.